# Ninja Forms - pull in some post related information

Tags: php, functions, plugin-ninja-forms

I am building a real estate website. There is a custom post type, called "Agents", that holds all the contact info, like the email address. I also have a custom post type called "Properties" where you can choose the agent who is in charge of it.

On the property detail page, there is a Ninja Contact Form. I need to pull the agents email address into that form to overwrite the Administrator Email Address that was put in, in the form settings. Does that make sense to someone?

$agent_email depends on $post->ID

the agent email address need to be included in ninja_forms_form_2, overwriting the administrator email from form settings.

Is there anyone out there who can start working on this with me? On my own, I am lost. I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks to all.

Mark

Comment: Swapping in dynamic email addresses seems pretty straight-forward. Here is a resource from Ninja Forms that details it. However, pulling in a specific email based on which "property" page the user is on will take some customization as this documentation assumes that the user will be selecting a "department" from a dropdown menu.

[Change Or Add Administrator Emails Addresses Based On User Values](http://ninjaforms.com/documentation/developer-api/code-examples/change-or-add-administrator-email-addresses-based/)

Comment: that sound promising but the customization part is the problem. The theme I use, had a contact form, that was using the agents email, based on the post id but it is not flexible, this is why I want to use ninja forms and add the feature to it.
The build in contact form was using this code on top of the form template. Maybe you see a way to use this to customize the ninja code.
`$agent_email = is_email( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'agent_email', true) );

if($agent_email ==''){
    if ( get_the_author_meta('user_level') !=10){
         $agent_email= get_the_author_meta( 'user_email'  );
     }
}`